# Regex to get last word from sentence of words separated by “/“?

Tags: regex

What would be the appropriate regex to get the last word in these sentences:

```
/hello/world        -> world
/foo/bar/good       -> good
/one/two/three/four -> four
```

Comment: Do you need to use regex?  Standard string functions can easily do this.

Comment: `/\/\w*$/` should work if you really need RegEx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
[^/]+$
```

which will match the last run of non-slash characters in a string.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.  I was going to use negative look-ahead but your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

for example in python:

```
import re
gg = re.compile("[^/]+$")
gg.findall("/hello/world")
```

or you can just use some more standard string library functions, again example in python:

```
("/hello/world").split("/")[-1]
```

Comment: No need to `split()` really, `s[s.rindex('/')+1:]` avoids creating an extra array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^/]+$
```

`[^/]` any character that is not`/`

`+` one or more

`$` anchored to end of the input